# why custom events do not need to be used with xxx.target.value"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular, just a question on custom events. For normal event binding, we have the following code below:

```
<input class="form-control" (input)="selectedProduct=$event.target.value" />
```

but for custom bindings, I saw code like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="..." [pa-attr]="getProducts().length < 6 ? 'bg-success' : 'bg-warning'" (pa-category)="newProduct.category=$event">
```

so why it is not :

```
<tr ... (pa-category)="newProduct.category=$event.target.value">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom components emit the value which can be caught by `$event`

Suppose,

this is the custom component:

```
<input class="form-control" (input)="selectedProduct=$event.target.value" (blur)="onBlur()"/>


@Output() exampleOutput= new EventEmitter();

onBlur() {
    exampleOutput.emit(selectedProduct)
}
```

Since `exampleOutput` is emitting the value directly, when you use `(exampleOutput)= "test = $event"` , test gets the value directly

Comment: thanks for your answer. So what should the `exampleOutput.emit()` be if I want the custom event should follow the same pattern as the first case, like `<tr ... (pa-category)="newProduct.category=$event.target.value">`

Comment: Something like this: `exampleOutput.emit({target : {value : selectedProduct}})`